# Plain sql query doesn't insert

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

### I wanna Insert values into my DB using a plain SQL query.

I don't get an error message, just nothing gets inserted.
I even checked to see if the values were in the variables, but they were fine.

- `excelDate` is a Datetime
- `excelDatePlusTimeSpan` is a DateTime
- `formattedDate` is a string

```cs
object[] paramItems = new object[]
{
    new SqlParameter("@ExcelDate", excelDate),
    new SqlParameter("@ExcelDatePlusTimeSpan", excelDatePlusTimeSpan),
    new SqlParameter("@FormattedDate", formattedDate),
};

int items = db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(@$"
    INSERT INTO DarsMissingSale (ProductNr, MissingSystem)
        SELECT Product_NR Product,  'Dars' AS MissingSystem
        From PRODUCTSALE PS 
        JOIN VARIATION V ON PS.VARIATION_CODE = V.VARIATION_CODE
        LEFT JOIN DarsSales DS 
        ON PS.PRODUCT_NR = DS.IdentificationNumber
        WHERE V.PRODUCT_TYPE = 3 and (DS.IdentificationNumber is Null) AND (ORDER_DATE  LIKE '@FormattedDate' OR (PurchaseDate BETWEEN @ExcelDate AND @ExcelDatePlusTimeSpan)) 
", paramItems);
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I followed the documentation on [this website](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5321286/Executing-Raw-SQL-Queries-using-Entity-Framework-C).
Maybe there is a problem with the `@` placeholders. But I don't think so.

Comment: This is a SQL query and has nothing to do with `EF Core`. Please update your question.

Comment: Can't find a method `.ExecuteSqlRaw()` associated to a context. Try using `.FromSqlRaw()` instead. [Here is a link to docs](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql).

Comment: @Codingwiz The user is saying there aren't any errors, so the `ExecuteSqlRaw` should be ok.  It looks like it has something to do with `EF Core`.  See [ExecuteSqlRaw Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlraw?view=efcore-7.0)

Comment: When I remove the "@" - Placeholder with a number or a string it inserts normaly

Comment: Maybe the @$ at the beginning of your sql string is the problem...

Comment: @Nico I need the @ symbol but I'll try removeing the $

Comment: The @ symbol lets you write a string in multi-line. The $ symbol lets you insert values inside the string (ex `$"test.. {variable} ..."`) and is not needed in this case.

Comment: @Nico unfortunately it didn't work, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I did a small code test using an insert statement and everything works fine (warning, avoid nullable values when using a parametrized query). Try executing your query in a Database first and see if it works.

Comment: @Codingwiz  I wrote and tested the query in SSMS and it worked. It works even when I use it in the code. But only if I replace the @ placeholders with the final values

Comment: @sDevPaul can you add an edit to your question with which part of the code that works and which does not ?

Comment: I often had problems when using DateTime stuff in SQL queries, maybe you need to convert your DateTime parameters to a formatted DateTime-string that the database understands.

Comment: @Nico I've tried doing that before. Didn't work

Comment: @sDevPaul You should always try to parametrize your queries, especially values from an user input, to avoid vulnerabilities such as XSS. But if there is no need to secure this part of the code, you can remove the @ symbols as you suggested.

Comment: @Codingwiz idk what I should edit because the code works, The Problem is that the placeholders such as `@ExcelDate` dont work. 

And my Senior Dev said that I should do it like this

Comment: When you tried your query in SSMS, you have actually typed in the datetime values - as text. It is worth a try to use new SqlParameter("@ExcelDate", excelDate.ToString()) and again excelDatePlusTimeSpan.ToString()

Comment: I don't think you need to quote around @FormattedDate - doesn't the paramatisation deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't work because the ' ' on the '@FormattedDate' placeholder weren't needed.

```cs
object[] paramItems = new object[]
{
    new SqlParameter("@ExcelDate", excelDate),
    new SqlParameter("@ExcelDatePlusTimeSpan", excelDatePlusTimeSpan),
    new SqlParameter("@FormattedDate", formattedDate),
};

int items = db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(@$"
    INSERT INTO DarsMissingSale (ProductNr, MissingSystem)
        SELECT Product_NR Product,  'Dars' AS MissingSystem
        From PRODUCTSALE PS 
        JOIN VARIATION V ON PS.VARIATION_CODE = V.VARIATION_CODE
        LEFT JOIN DarsSales DS 
        ON PS.PRODUCT_NR = DS.IdentificationNumber
        WHERE V.PRODUCT_TYPE = 3 and (DS.IdentificationNumber is Null) AND (ORDER_DATE  LIKE @FormattedDate OR (PurchaseDate BETWEEN @ExcelDate AND @ExcelDatePlusTimeSpan)) 
", paramItems);
```

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT INTO...SELECT` will silently insert zero rows if the `SELECT` portion returns no data. You have a few places that could cause no data in the `SELECT` such as the first `JOIN` and the `WHERE` clause.

Run just the `SELECT` portion of your SQL by itself in a SQL client/IDE, find out why that is returning zero rows, then fix it and put it back into your `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` code.